# I am getting same highchart in pdf using jspdf when I am downloading the pdf with dynamic ids on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts, jspdf

I am using jspdf to capture the content of Hichchart which generating dynamically with dynamic id onclick. Here when I click submit1 button different highchart will generate with dynamic id.Again when I click download button it will download the dynamically created chart content in pdf.I can able to download but same chart is downloading again instead different chart on the page. I have updated the code to demo here 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3hJcC8pgzZxXPLWpfBw?p=preview ,Can anyone please help me, I am just putting the html and javascript code here.

### html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jspdf.debug.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/releases/download/v0.6.2/pdfkit.js"></script>
  <script src="rgbcolor.js"></script>
  <script src="canvg.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <input type="button" id="download"  value="download" /> click to console
  <div><button id="button1" class="button1">submit1</button></div>
```

### script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var index = 0;
    var id = [];
    $('#button1').on('click', function() {
        $('body').append($("<div id='chart" + index + "'></div>"));

        Highcharts.chart('chart' + index, {
           title: {
        text: 'Chart-'+index+''
    },
            series: [{
                data: [1, 2, 3]
            }]
        });
        var temp = "chart" + index + "";
        console.log(temp);
        id.push(temp);

        index++;
    });

    $('#download').on('click', function() {
console.log(id);
  var doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt', 'a4', true);
  var elementHandler = {
    '#ignorePDF': function(element, renderer) {
      return true;
    }
  };

  var source = document.getElementById("top-content");
  doc.fromHTML(source, 15, 15, {
    'width': 560,
    'elementHandlers': elementHandler
  });

  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
   var elements = id;

 // console.log(xx);
  for (let i in elements) {
      console.log(elements[i]);
      var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var canvasIE = document.createElement('canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var data1 = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
      canvg(canvas, data1);
      var svgBlob = new Blob([data1], {
        type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
      });

      var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
        context.canvas.width = $("#"+elements[i]).find('svg').width();
        context.canvas.height = $("#"+elements[i]).find('svg').height();

        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        // freeing up the memory as image is drawn to canvas
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        var dataUrl;
        if (isIEBrowser()) { // Check of IE browser 
          var svg = $(elements[i]).highcharts().container.innerHTML;
          canvg(canvasIE, svg);
          dataUrl = canvasIE.toDataURL('image/JPEG');
        } else {
          dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        }

        doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'JPEG', 20, 150, 560, 350);

          var bottomContent = document.getElementById("bottom-content");
  doc.fromHTML(bottomContent, 15, 700, {
    'width': 560,
    'elementHandlers': elementHandler
  });
         doc.fromHTML(source, 15, 15, {
    'width': 560,
    'elementHandlers': elementHandler
  });
  doc.addPage();
      };

      img.src = url;

    }


  setTimeout(function() {
    doc.save('TestChart.pdf');
  }, 2000);

});
});
function isIEBrowser() {
  var ieBrowser;
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

  if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // Internet Explorer
  {
    ieBrowser = true;
  } else //Other browser
  {
    console.log('Other Browser');
    ieBrowser = false;
  }

  return ieBrowser;
};
```

Comment: Can anyone please help me

Comment: When you have two charts using submit button, and then you click on download button then what should happen? It should generate pdf of last chart or it should generate pdf of both charts?

Comment: pdf of both charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two problems in your code.

First, you use `document.querySelector('svg');` which return only first svg element - you should use `document.querySelectorAll('svg');` and then get the right element `svg[i]`.

Second, it looks like that you have problem with asynchronous in your code - helped change all declarations `var` to `let`.

Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/epHnjnPhWFUdtic97jNA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for you help I need one more help Can I put image to every page as logo I tried inside loop but image was not coming,text were coming but image were not coming, let images = document.getElementById("image");
  doc.fromHTML(source, 15, 15, {
    'width': 560,
    'elementHandlers': elementHandler
  }); inside loop I added
I have already image in my project application in html inside div id 'image'

Comment: Hi carreankush, please provide me with live example.

Comment: I have updated in this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3hJcC8pgzZxXPLWpfBw?p=preview ,  Here footer is displaying in every page but image is not displaying in all pages,I have already used let logo = document.getElementById("logo");
   doc.fromHTML(logo, 15, 200, {
    'width': 560,
    'elementHandlers': elementHandler
  });  same like footer.

Comment: Can you please help me. I tried but I didn't get solution

Comment: Hi carreankush, Have you already fixed this problem? Your description in the example indicates that you have solved it.

Comment: Still not resolved Can you please help me here is the updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3hJcC8pgzZxXPLWpfBw?p=preview

Comment: Element with id `logo` does not exist : `let logo = document.getElementById("logo");` Please check another value: http://plnkr.co/edit/Fsy6KpwhqFLX3E8P0ue2?p=preview

Comment: I updated here as you told event though I am not getting  http://plnkr.co/edit/KbJy2T58qX02bvE0IUHv?p=preview

Comment: Hi carreankush, Sorry but I do not know well the plugins you used. I can help you with Highcharts. I think that you should create another topic for your question.

Comment: Ok no problem, Thanks